# how to send \r\n in the middle of message via telnet(or some other tool)

Tags: telnet

I need to send to localhost, given port messages like SOME_NUMBER\r\nANOTHER_NUMBER\r\n  and recieve answers.
I tried telnet, but can't make it send \r\n. I tried double and single quotes but in all attempts it treats \r\n as 4 usual characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a shell in a UNIX/LINUX/OSX style operating system, you can for example use netcat `nc <HOST> <PORT>` to open a TCP connection to your destination. Then type the key sequence `CTRL-M` for carriage return and the `CTRL-J` for line feed.

Or you open the connection using `nc -c <HOST> <PORT>`, this makes netcat send CR/LF whenever you hit RETURN.